# To show that the normalizer of a proper sub algebra K of L includes K properly

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra, $K$ a proper sub algebra of $L$. Prove that $N(K)$ includes $K$ properly. Here, $N(K)$ is the normalizer of $K$ in $L$ given by $N(K)=\{x\in L : [x,K]\subseteq K\}$.

I wanted to know what I did was correct. (I have just started studying Lie algebras so please let me know if something is mathematically incorrect.) Here's what I tried:

Let $L^{0}=L\supseteq L^{1} \supseteq...\supseteq L^{n}=0$ be the descending central series of $L$. (We can write such a terminating series as $L$ is nilpotent). As $K$ is a proper subset of $L$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that $L^{m+1}\subseteq K$ but $L^{m} \nsubseteq K$. This is because if $L^{p}\subseteq K$ for all $p$ then for $p=0$ we will get $K=L$, a contradiction. So we have, $L^{m+1}\subseteq K \subsetneq L^{m}$ (can we write this inequality?)

Now, let $x\in L^{m}$ such that $x$ is not in $K$. Thus $[x,K]\subseteq [L,L^{m}]=L^{m+1}\subseteq K$. Thus, $x\in N(K)$ but $x$ does not belong to $K$.

Comment: You argue correctly there is a maximal $m$ with $L^m \not \subseteq K$ but then suddenly you claim to know $K \subsetneq L^m$. How so?

Comment: I cannot seem to come up with a proof of that. And if this is not true, then I cannot even write that $[x,K] \subseteq [L,L^{m}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can't write that : $K \subsetneq L^m$. But you don't need this inclusion :

if $x \in L^m$ such that $x$ is not in $K$ : $[x,K]\subseteq [L^mL]=L^{m+1} \subseteq K$ and you conclude like you did.

Comment: Oh! Yes, as $x\in L^{m}$ and $K$ is obviously in $L$ so $[x,K]\subseteq[L^{m},L]$. Thank you!